# trying to add substring to array every third character

Tags: java

In short, I'm trying to take a string then divide it every three characters, adding those three characters to an array as it progresses.

The initial input to the function (rawData) look something like this:

```
ATGCCACTATGGTAG
```

but can vary in length.

I'm trying to convert the above data (representing nucleotides) into the individual codons like so:

```
[ATG,CCA,CTA,TGG,TAG]
```

note that every chunk of 3 is now indexed into an array.
This is my code:

```
public static void codonList(String rawData) {
        int previous = 0;
        String[] codons = new String[rawData.length() / 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < rawData.length(); i++) {

            previous++;
            // goes through each
            // split at every third then append to end of codon string
            if (previous % 3 == 0) {
                String chunk = rawData.substring(previous - 3, previous);
                codons[i] = chunk;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codons));
            }
        }

    }
```

and its output:

```
[null,null,AGT,null,null]
```

I'm 90% sure it's a simple fix but can't seem to get it figured out. If someone can provide some insight that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: HINT: `String chunk = rawData.substring(i*3, i*3+3);`.  And get rid of `previous`.

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues.

1. you are iterating through the whole string, you only want to create `rawData.length()/3` codons.
2. As Kevin hinted, get 3 character chucks: `String chunk = rawData.substring(i*3, i*3+3);`
3. only print the array when you are done processing the string.

```
    public static void codonList(String rawData) {
        String[] codons = new String[rawData.length() / 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < rawData.length() / 3; i++) {
            // goes through each
            // split at every third then append to end of codon string
            String chunk = rawData.substring(i*3, i*3+3);
            codons[i] = chunk;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codons));
    }
```

Output:

> [ATG, CCA, CTA, TGG, TAG]

Comment: yeah, all these solutions that you guys have provided work great, nice to see multiple methods. Having that print inside the for loop was just for debugging reasons. Forgot to put it back out. Thanks for the input!